# Finding the longest sequence of cards with dynamic programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm attempting to write a program which is supposed to find the length of the longest sequence of cards (Crazy eights style) in a shuffled deck using dynamic programming.

we are not allowed to use the standard library (this includes vectors).

So far this is what I've written:

The program reads the deck from a file, stores it in an array.
Then from within the `crazyUp()` function, I'm attempting to compare each element from within the array with the previous element, if they are equal, we compare with `dict[]` which is supposed to act as a hash table for Memoization.

I can't wrap my head around why the `maxLength` is always returning `1`, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The file contains data for the cards like so:

```
9C
9D
5C
AC
4D
3H
KD
4S
```

For a total of 52 lines (52 cards).

The sequence is as follows:

if a card's Rank or suit is similar to the one before it, add it to that sequence.

Think of 8 as a universal card that can match with any other card, hence the name, crazy eight!

Example:

```
9C
9D
5C
AC
8S
```

Would be a valid sequence.

However:

```
5C
9H
3D
```

would be completely skipped as none of them are "like" another.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int crazyUp(string[]);
int index = 0;

string cards[55];

int dict[55];
int dictIndex = 0;

int main()
{
    string file;
    string word;
    cout << "Please input a file's name..." << endl;
    cin >> file;

    ifstream fileName(file);

    while (fileName >> word) {
        cards[index++] = word;
    }
    
    crazyUp(cards);
    
}


int crazyUp(string cards[]) {
    dict[0] = 0;
    int maxLength = 0;
    int length;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        length = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
            if (cards[i] == cards[j]) {
                length = max(length, dict[j]+1);
            }
            

        }
        dict[i] = length;
        maxLength = max(maxLength, length);
        cout << maxLength;
    }

    return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: Here's a piece of advice: Don't solve 2 problems at once. First, implement the solution using the STL (vectors, algorithms) etc. Once you've solved the problem, *then* replace the STL stuff with your own code. And just because you're replacing say, a `vector`, you don't have to implement `std::vector`, just write the bits needed for this problem.

Comment: Won't `cards[i] == cards[j]` always be false as all the cards are different?

Comment: @AlanBirtles nope, tested that condition, it's true on some instances.

Comment: Are you sure? how did you test it? what were the values of the 2 elements when it returned true?

Comment: Can you edit the question with the rules of what forms a sequence? Not all of us know what "crazy eights" is.

Comment: @Botje Done, please check the question again.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Basically throw a simple cout for that particular card, and it actually printed some different cards, I'm a bit lost at this point, been looking at this for the past 4 hours.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? I can't see any way that your current code would do what you want

Comment: I understand 9C -> 9D, and 5C -> AC -> 8S, but why are 9D and 5C similar? You need to be able to explain this to the computer as well.